# User Profile Service Strikes Again

Tags: user-profile-service

Before someone links me to Habar I know that site intamatley. Usually I can overcome UPS issues with the August 2011 CUs and correctly set permissions for the app pool account. I have a current issue where I can't finish creating the Sync Connection for the UPSA.

I can fill the details out and I can see the top of the AD structure but I cannot expand this tree. I don't see any error but I assume the operation times out. I can also select the entrie structure with 'Select All' and attempt to click 'OK' but this triggers an operation that I'm not even sure is working. Eventually this times out, it doesn't actually go to the 'Processing' screen as it usually does. I've increased the time out to 40 seconds now and was going to try heading upwards of that, or even try creating another UPSA. The problem is that this is a migration and the audiences would have to be re-created from scratch.

Theres nothing else I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was network related as suspected:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/3ffb5c99-176f-425e-9409-0fbb6762bf17/

On the SharePoint server goto :

> Computer Configuration \ Windows Settings \ Security Settings \ Local Policies \ Security Options. Then select "network security: LDAP client signing requirements", change to "None".
>
> Reboot the box

Comment: Please, mark your Q as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly set the Replicate Directory Changes for the Sync account as well as add the Sync account to the Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access group in Active Directory if you're running 2003 native mode or below?

Comment: That was missed but still no dice. The odd thing is that the connection times out when I put a specific name of a DC in instead of the name of the actual domain forest. I believe there is some kind of connection issue between AD and FIM. Almost ready to escalate to Microsoft support

Comment: Are there any network restrictions in place?