# Problem with User Profile Synchronization Service

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, forefront

I have been facing the problem with my sharepoint user profile synchronization service for almost 2 months.

I have followed exactly the http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx  article and yet having problems.

The user profile service is running fine.
I am using the farm account to start the user profile synchronization service.
However, it takes around 5 min saying "Starting" and then stops.

While starting, I followed the "Windows Services".
I noticed that the "Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service" once starts and then stops, before the User Profile Synchronization Service stops.

The sp_ups account has been delegated "Replicating Directory Changes" permission and the farm account is also a member of administrators group and has the permission to log on locally which tells that I do not have any permission problems.

I have also installed the February 2012 hotfix but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: this kind of issues, the solution of it likely never related to the main problem. for instance i wrote the simple web part and after i installed on my site, web part won't worked and that was insane because it worked on other my coworkers computers, and finally i figure it out that my sharepoint drive was full. i suggest you prepare this situation on a test computer and see what happens and if there was no problem, you should look for the differences between two computers and their configurations.

Comment: what was the error with the webapplication
Can you please explain it in detail

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this solution as mentioned in another thread over here :- [User Profile Strikes Again](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26718/user-profile-service-strikes-again)

Comment: Thank you guys
I found the cause.
There was some error with my web application and by recreating them solved the problem.